# How to print out string when isdigit() is False [Python 2.7]

Tags: python

I'm making a code where other than the integers 1-12 is the input it will return an error message (string).

The first string message I want return is when the number is greater than 12 (which I already solved). "Doesn't exist".

The second string message I want return is when a string is input and not a number. "Unrecognized number".

I need help doing this, and I'm not sure how.

The following is my current code.

```
days_in_month = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]

def how_many_days(month_number):
if month_number > 12:
    return "Doesn't exist"
if how_many_days.isdigit(month_number) == False:
    return "Unrecognized number"
return days_in_month[month_number - 1]

print how_many_days(13)
print how_many_days(5)
print how_many_days(12)
print how_many_days(13)
print how_many_days("January")
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: What went wrong? I assume its about `isdigit` doesn't take arguments. `isdigit` is a method and works on its own object. `if how_many_days.isdigit() == False:` may be what you want.

Comment: actually... looking more closely, you passed in an integer which doesn't have an `isdigit` .... its an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably do not need to set up safeguards. Just try out the argument on your list and see if it works:

```
def how_many_days(month_number):
    try:
        return days_in_month[month_number - 1]
    except TypeError:
        print "Unrecognized number"
        raise
    except IndexError:
        print "Doesn't exist"
        raise
```

This follows the EAFP (**E**asier to **A**sk for **F**orgiveness than **P**ermission) philosophy as against *looking before you leap*.